# Button to add rows to html table, and content

Tags: jquery, html, auto-increment, tabular

I have a table on my website which I use as a navigation. My pages are stored in a database and the links just call the new content into the content div, using the primary key id.

I have now added buttons to add new pages and edit current ones, however when I submit the new page button. Is there a way to create an extra row, with the appropriate text which draws the right content? (Auto increment of the id on each link, starting from 10 up), assuming this will require jQuery?

```
<ul>
  <a href="index.php?id=2"><li>Introduction</li></a>
  <a href="index.php?id=3"><li>Setting up program/Adjusting preference</li></a>
  <a href="index.php?id=4"><li>Choosing plugins</li></a>
  <a href="index.php?id=5"><li>Basic Features/Functions</li></a>
  <a href="index.php?id=6"><li>Creating a Drum Beat/Envelopes</li></a>
  <a href="index.php?id=7"><li>Creating a Bass Wobble</li></a>
  <a href="index.php?id=8"><li>Utilizing Plugins</li></a>
  <a href="index.php?id=9"><li>Advanced Tools/Features</li></a>
  <a href="index.php?id=10"><li>New Page</li></a>
</ul>
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: it would be easier for people to help if you posted the html, css and the javascript/jquery code. thanks.

Comment: I can't understand what are you exactly trying to do. add more information/code and you will be answered quickly